# Pass CSV file to Swift 2 File for UI Automation Testing

Tags: swift2

Hi i am absolute beginner to the swift and Xcode tool. I am trying to Test application through UI Testing bundle introduced from Xcode 7+. I want to migrate my hardcoded data from scripts to cvs file. please help.

currently i have created a class csvScanner but it is showing Argument labels(contentsOfFile:,encoding :,error) error  in code below

import Foundation

class CSVScanner {

```
class func debug(string:String){

    print("CSVScanner: \(string)")
}

class func runFunctionOnRowsFromFile(theColumnNames:Array<String>, withFileName theFileName:String, withFunction theFunction:(Dictionary<String, String>)->()) {

    if let strBundle = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(theFileName, ofType: "csv") {

        var encodingError:NSError? = nil

        if let fileObject = NSString(contentsOfFile: strBundle, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: &encodingError){

            var fileObjectCleaned = fileObject.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\r", withString: "\n")

            fileObjectCleaned = fileObjectCleaned.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\n\n", withString: "\n")

            let objectArray = fileObjectCleaned.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")

            for anObjectRow in objectArray {

                let objectColumns = anObjectRow.componentsSeparatedByString(",")

                var aDictionaryEntry = Dictionary<String, String>()

                var columnIndex = 0

                for anObjectColumn in objectColumns {

                    aDictionaryEntry[theColumnNames[columnIndex]] = anObjectColumn.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\"", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch, range: nil)

                    columnIndex++
                }

                if aDictionaryEntry.count>1{
                    theFunction(aDictionaryEntry)
                }else{

                    CSVScanner.debug("No data extracted from row: \(anObjectRow) -> \(objectColumns)")
                }
            }
        }else{
            CSVScanner.debug("Unable to load csv file from path: \(strBundle)")

            if let errorString = encodingError?.description {

                CSVScanner.debug("Received encoding error: \(errorString)")
            }
        }
    }else{
        CSVScanner.debug("Unable to get path to csv file: \(theFileName).csv")
    }
}
```

}

Thanks in advance

Comment: a small bit of reformatting is needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Xcode 7+, you are also using Swift 2.  Instead of passing an error pointer to the method, you need to use `try`.

The method signature has changed to `convenience init(contentsOfFile path: String,
encoding enc: UInt) throws`.

(Note: no `error:`.)

Comment: I am still getting errors in formatting can you please post working version of above class it would be of great help.